# IE 9 - Link (React Router) - Link click reload entire page

Tags: reactjs, react-router, internet-explorer-9

On Internet Explorer 9, when I click an anchor generated by Link component (React Router) my react app reload the entire page and I lose JS's and Redux's state.

I tried on Chrome, Safari and IE (10 & 11) all works fine and I can navigate through the app without losing the states!

I've 16.8.4 version of React, 4.3.1 version for (React Router & React Router Dom) and 4.0.1 version of Redux.

The actual result is that the page is reloaded when I do click in the anchor and this causes that the entire state have lost.

The expected behavior is that I can navigate through my app without get the page reloaded.

Comment: Can you show us how you've written the link? Are you sure you didn't write it as external link?

Comment: Here is the code:

`<Link to="/quiz/play" onClick={(e) => this.goToPresentationQuiz(q, e)} data-parent={"quizParent" + q.levelNumber} className="btn btn-primary btn-sm btn-play-now btn-unbordered applyBg">PLAY NOW</Link> `

On this way, the Link component works fine with the other browsers!

Comment: If you want to refresh the partial view of the page, you could  using JQuery Ajax to re-populate the page content.

Comment: @ZhiLv-MSFT        
I'm not using Jquery for this. Sorry but your answer is not useful for this case. Thanks anyway!